# execution of a c program in GCC compiler

Tags: gcc

I have wrote a c program in gedit and opened terminal where the following symbol shown as

>

and now i tried to execute the program as

> gcc filename.c

and am getting the output as

gcc: command not found

what is the error in doing this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that gcc is not installed.  The steps for installing it depend on which Linux distro you are using.  For Debian-based systems, you should try

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

For Red Hat-based systems, try

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install gcc. Try `sudo apt-get install gcc` (actually, `sudo apt-get install build-essential` is a better idea), or `sudo yum install gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using gedit, I'm going to infer that you're running on some Linux system.

To clarify, what you tried to do with this command...

> gcc filename.c

.. was to *compile* your program, filename.c. After executing this command successfully you would then need to run the compiled executable, which by default would be named **a.out**.

As per the other poster, the most likely cause of the error in invoking gcc is that you don't have the compiler installed. If you're running on Ubuntu or another Debian-based distro you can install gcc with apt-get; on other distributions like SuSE or Red Hat you can use yum.